# PHPMailer not sending to hotmail e-mail

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to use the PHP Mailer for the first time. I set up a SMTP account and entered in my information below:

```
<?php
   require("cscie12/final    project/PHPMailer/PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.PHPMailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "ssrs.reachmail.net";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = "25";
$mail->SMTPAuth = plain;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "BRYANSAY\bryan";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "***********"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "bryan@reachmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "Contact Form";
$mail->AddAddress("bryan.sayles@hotmail.com", "Bryan Sayles");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Contact Form";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
}
echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

But I don't receive an e-mail. I get this posted on my page:

```
IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP $mail->Host = "ssrs.reachmail.net"; //            specify main and backup server $mail->Port = "25"; $mail->SMTPAuth = plain; // turn on SMTP authentication $mail->Username = "BRYANSAY\bryan"; // SMTP username $mail->Password = "********"; // SMTP password $mail->From = "bryan@reachmail.com"; $mail->FromName = "Contact Form"; $mail->AddAddress("bryan.sayles@hotmail.com", "Bryan Sayles"); $mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap to 50 characters $mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz"); // add attachments $mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg"); // optional name $mail->IsHTML(true); // set email format to HTML $mail->Subject = "Contact Form"; $mail->Body = "This is the HTML message body in bold!"; $mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients"; if(!$mail->Send()) { echo "Message could not be sent.
"; echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo; exit; } } echo "Message has been sent"; ?>
```

I'm missing something somewhere but not sure what. Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format:

```
<?php
    include 'library.php'; // include the library file
    include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
    include "classes/class.smtp.php";
    if(isset($_POST["send"])){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $mail   = new PHPMailer; // call the class 
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";

        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Port = 465; //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        //$mail->SMTPAuth = false; //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "your mail id"; //Username for SMTP authentication any valid email created in your domain
        $mail->Password = "your password"; //Password for SMTP authentication
        $mail->AddReplyTo("abcd@gmail.com", "Reply name"); //reply-to address
        $mail->SetFrom("your mail id", "your name"); //From address of the mail
        // put your while loop here like below,
        $mail->Subject = "Your SMTP Mail"; //Subject od your mail
        $mail->AddAddress($email, "Asif18"); //To address who will receive this email
        $mail->MsgHTML("<b>Hi, your first SMTP mail has been received."); //Put your body of the message you can place html code here
         //Attach a file here if any or comment this line, 

        $send = $mail->Send(); //Send the mails
        if($send){
            echo '<center><h3 style="color:#009933;">Mail sent successfully</h3></center>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<center><h3 style="color:#FF3300;">Mail error: </h3></center>'.$mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Send mails using SMTP and PHP in PHP Mailer using our own server or gmail server by Asif18</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="send mails using smpt in php, php mailer for send emails in smtp, use gmail for smtp in php, gmail smtp server name"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Send mails using SMTP and PHP in PHP Mailer using our own server or gmail server"/>
    <style>
    .as_wrapper{
        font-family:Arial;
        color:#333;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .mytable{
        padding:20px;
        border:2px dashed #17A3F7;
        width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div class="as_wrapper">
        <h1>Send mails using SMTP and PHP in PHP Mailer using our own server or gmail server</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <table class="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send via SMTP" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
require("cscie12/final    project/PHPMailer/PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.PHPMailer.php");
```

to

```
require("cscie12/finalproject/PHPMailer/PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.PHPMailer.php");
```

---

```
$mail->Username = "BRYANSAY\bryan";
```

to

```
$mail->Username = 'BRYANSAY\bryan';
```

or escape the `\b`

```
$mail->Username = "BRYANSAY\\bryan";
```

---

And remove the last bracket

```
}
```

---

If you still have problems make sure you read:
https://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx